# Subtracting from a column that has duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

So I need to subtract the delivered quantity from my "Consuming" Table from the quantity on hand from the "qitems" table. But, there are duplicate items and it only subtracts it once for each item. What should I do? I have attached a screenshot of the tables. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
Update qi
Set qi.QtyOnHand = (qi.QtyOnHand - c.delqty)
From qitem qi
Inner Join Consuming c
on qi.itemname = c.itemname
```

[image]

Comment: You need to group `consuming` and sum the quantity before joining. And *please* don't join on `itemname`! Use a primary key and foreign key.

Comment: Your syntax is not MySQL syntax.  Are you sure about the database tag?

Comment: I fixed it! Sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me assume you are using SQL Server, based on the syntax.  The idea is the same regardless of the database.  You need to aggregate before doing the update:

```
Update qi
    Set qi.QtyOnHand = (qi.QtyOnHand - c.delqty)
    From qitem qi Inner Join
         (select c.itemname, sum(c.delqty) as delqty
          from Consuming c
          group by c.itemname
         ) c
         on qi.itemname = c.itemname;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was perfect